# Karamata-like inequality.

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math

Prove the following statement (preferebly using Karamata):

If a differentiable function has a single inflexion
point and is evaluated at n arbitrary reals with a fixed sum, any minimum or maximum must occur where
some n − 1 variables are equal. And determine in what cases the minimum or the maximum occurs under this circumstances.

I have proven that the minimum occurs when the function goes from convex to concave(in increasing order), but studying some examples this looks like and actually the vice-versa occurs, namely the maximum occurs when the function goes from concave to convex, but i can't find any flaw in my solution, neither to prove the supposely correct statement. Please help :)

Comment: Minimum or maximum of what?

Comment: Namely: $f(x)$ is concave/convex for all $x \le s$ and convex/concave (respectively) for all $x\ge s$. Prove that iff $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$ have fixed sum then $f(x_1)+f(x_2)+..+f(x_n)$ attains maximum or minimum when $n-1$ of $x_i$ are equal, and determine in what cases it attains either maximum or minimum(when concave-> convex or convex->concave).

Comment: Can anyone help?